# query 2 tables and get all records from table A and include one field from 2nd

Tags: sql

table 1

```
col1 col 2
A     aaa
B     bbb
C     ccc
```

table 2

```
col1 col 2  col3
A     aaa    xx
B     bbb    yy
C     ccc    zz
D     ddd    hh
E     eee    mm
```

How to write a query where i get all of table1 data and only col3 to existing records of Table 1. table1 has only 50 records and Table2 has 100k. But i need only all 50 records of Table 1  and only col3 added to the record by joining 
table1. col1 = table2.col1

Comment: So you do know about join. Did you try anything?

Comment: Please show the SQL query you have already written that doesn't behave the way you want; that will give readers a clearer idea of what you're thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the description, I would suggest this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.col1,
    t2.col2,
    t2.col3
FROM 
    table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 AS t2 ON (t2.col1 = t1.col1 AND t2.col2 = t1.col2)
```

---

The `SELECT` clause determines what columns will appear in the result set. Your description gives us some assistance here.

For a join, choosing the correct join type is important to what query you are making. Your description is helpful for this:

> How to write a query where I get all of table1 data and only col3 to existing records of Table 1.

- “get all of table1” implies that the result set should include all columns from that table.

  ```
  SELECT table1.col1, table1.col2 […]
  ```
- “get all of table1” implies that table1 is the primary source in the `FROM` clause.

  ```
  […] FROM table1 […]
  ```
- “only col3 [from table2]” implies that the result set should also include that column.

  ```
  SELECT […] table2.col3
  ```
- “only […] to existing records of table1” implies that the join type is `INNER JOIN`.

  ```
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2 […]
  ```
- “only col3 to existing records of table1” implies that is the join condition.

  ```
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.[…] = table1.[…]
  ```

But you don't specify exactly what condition tells us what records are equivalent between the tables. Shall we assume that the condition is for all columns named the same to have the same value?

```
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (table2.col1 = table1.col1 AND table2.col2 = table1.col2)
```

We will be using the tables several times, so it's good practice to set concise `AS` aliases in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: the second join helped.

Comment: @pali101, thanks for the comment. If this answers your question, would you [mark this as the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Answer (score 1):

You want `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.col1 = t1.col1;
```

Comment: I am getting more than 50 records . i need only 50 records. i tried distinct still..

Comment: @pali101. . .  What if `table2` has different more than one value in `col3` for `col1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try left join:

```
    SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3
    FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
         table2 t2
         ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2;
```